# Why is the data from remix different from that from my computer when compiling the same contract using the same version of solidity complier?

Tags: solc

I downloaded the 0.5.7+commit.6da8b019 version of solidity compiler, compiled an ERC20 contract locally using the compiler, and got the binary data. Then I also copied the ERC20 contract and pasted it on the remix website. I chose the same version of solidity compiler there to compile the contract. However, I found that the data is different from that I got locally. Does anyone have any idea why it is like that? Thanks in advance. The two data are pasted below.

Data from the local compiler:
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

Data from remix:
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

Comment: not sure the raw contract code helps much here except making people freak out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the only difference in the emitted bytecode is in the [contract metadata](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata.html) hash. This is likely due to something like using a different source file name.